# Why is surgery along a framed link well defined?

Tags: manifolds, knot-theory, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $L=L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \cdots \cup L_n $ be a framed link in $ S^3 $. I want to perform the surgery along $L$ to get a new manifold $M$.

By definition, to perform this surgery, I must perform the surgery along each component $L_i$. Why isn't this dependent on the order in which I perform the surgeries?

I also have another question: Let $M$ be the manifold obtained by surgery along $L$. It is known that $M$ bounds a $4$-manifold $X$. Why is $X$ of the form $D^4 \cup 2$-handles?

Here is what I know about this second question. Let $K$ is a knot in $S^3$ and $M$ the manifold obtained by surgery. Let $W$ be the manifold obtained by gluing appropriately a $2$-handle on $ S^3 \times \lbrace 1 \rbrace \subset S^3\times [0,1]$. $W$ is a cobordism from $S^3$ to $M$. Hence $X=W \cup_{S^3} D^4$ is a $4$-manifold with boundary $M$. Is it clear that $X$ is of the form $D^4 \cup$ a $2$-handle? If the answer is yes, does this adapt to the link case?

Edit: I will try to answer my second question. Start from the $4$-ball and glue $2$-handles $D^2 \times D^2$ as follows. To glue the $2$-handle I must specify a homeo $ \partial D^2 \times D^2 $ to some solid torus in $\partial D^4=S^3$. For that, use the tubular neighbourhoods of the link components so that the meridian of $ \partial D^2 \times D^2 $ goes to the curve specified by the framing of the components. In other words, the effect on $S^3=\partial D^4$ of gluing these $2$-handles is precisely to change do the surgery of $S^3$ along $K$. Hence the boundary of this $ D^4 \cup 2$-handles is precisely $M$. This seems like working, so why do textbooks usually bother with this $S^3 \times [0,1]$ construction?

Comment: For the first one, if you think of each component of the link as defining a solid torus to be removed as well as a homeomorphism that tells you how to glue in another torus, why shouldn't it be obvious that the order doesn't matter? (In fact, you don't have to take them one component at a time but could simply think of surgery as removing a disjoint union of solid tori and gluing in another disjoint union of solid tori.)

Comment: If I start with $L_1$, I get a manifold $M_1$. Now the remainder of the link can be seen as belonging to $M_1$. Performing the other surgeries gives a sequence of manifolds $M_2$,...,$M_n$. Seeing it like this, it doesn't seem obvious that the final result should be the same depending on the order.

Comment: @Lepanais Reordering will give you a homeomorphism between the result of doing the surgeries in different order. Intuition is that the surgery only changes the manifold in a neighborhood of the cusp, not anywhere else, so the changes are disjoint from each other.

Comment: The comment of @Neal regarding "disjointness" of changes can be made rigorous by using some simple properties of quotient maps. The idea is that if the set of nontrivial decomposition elements of a quotient map is partitioned into finitely many subdecompositions, you can take the quotient by those subdecompositions one at a time in any order. No matter what order you pick, the composition of the resulting quotient maps is the original quotient maps.